# Creating A D3 Timeline to show Sensor Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I really like the d3 timeline example shown in this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034

However, for my purposes, I want to use a similar display to show how how long one of my sensors is receiving information from a target.

```
[
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 30},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 30},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 45},
    {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 45},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 45},
    {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 45},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor3", "time": 45},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor4", "time": 45},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 45},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 60},
    {"target":"3c", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 60},
    {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 60},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 60},
    {"target":"3c", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 60},
    {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 60},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor3", "time": 60},
    {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor3", "time": 60},
    {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor4", "time": 60},
    {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor4", "time": 60}
]
```

**This is just a sample of my full data set, for clarity.

So in this example, the first sensor picks up a reading at 30 seconds, by 45 seconds all four sensors have gotten readings from target 1 AND picked up readings from target 2.

To compare this data to the link, I figured the "lanes" would be the targets. However, unlike the example, there is no "end" time. I would simply stop receiving information.

Thoughts on how to specify an "end" to each of these sensor blocks?

Comment: What format is your raw data being stored in? JSON?

Comment: That is correct. It is being stored as a JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at AlaSql: https://github.com/agershun/alasql

For example, you could sort your data like:

```
var data = [
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 30},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 30},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 45},
  {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 45},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 45},
  {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 45},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor3", "time": 45},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor4", "time": 45},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 45},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 60},
  {"target":"3c", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 60},
  {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor1", "time": 60},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 60},
  {"target":"3c", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 60},
  {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor2", "time": 60},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor3", "time": 60},
  {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor3", "time": 60},
  {"target":"1a", "id":"Sensor4", "time": 60},
  {"target":"2b", "id":"Sensor4", "time": 60}
];

var res = alasql("SELECT [target], id, MIN(time) AS start, MAX(time) AS [end] FROM ? GROUP BY [target], id, start, [end]",[data]);
```

AlaSql also works well with d3.js. See: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/d3.js